# Why does a matrix PDE $ \hat{M}_{ij}(t) v_j(t) = 0$ imply $| \hat{M}_{ij}(t) | (v_1(t)+v_2(t)+\dots) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

In a recent paper by Pogorui et al (2021) found [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9091/9/8/147/pdf) (see the lines leading into eq. 3), it is asserted that the matrix PDE
[image]

Implies the following PDE for the sum $f(x,t)=f(x,0,t)+f(x,1,t)$:
[image]

**Question:**

Why is it that the matrix equation being equal to zero implies that the determinant of the matrix multipled by the sum of the vector elements equals zero?

**Bonus Question:**
How does this generalize when the matrix elements $M_{11}$ and $M_{22}$ do not commute?

Comment: Think about it this way: $M\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\v_2 \end{pmatrix}=0$ so $M \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & -1\\v_2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & *\\0 & *\end{pmatrix}  $. So $\det\left(M \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & -1\\v_2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right) = \det(M)\det\begin{pmatrix} v_1 & -1\\v_2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}= \det(M)(v_1+v_2) =0$

Comment: I'm not too familiar with matrix operators so this is kind of my guess.

Comment: @DogeChan, you can generalize this to arbitrary dimensions by considering e.g. $V = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & 1 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\ v_2 & -1 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\ v_3 & 0 & -1  & 1 & 0 \\ v_4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\ v_5 & 0 &0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$ The last row changes a bit based on the parity of $n$ in the $n\times n$ case. Then if $Mv = 0,$ with $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ we have $\det(MV) = \det(M)\det(V) =  \pm \det(M)(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i) = 0$

Comment: @DogeChan I think this is probably the best answer I will get. It does make sense... Clever! If you post as an answer I'll accept provided nothing miraculously better comes along

Comment: @F_M_ I am not concerned with the higher dimensional case, although that is an equally clever generalization! I am more interested in the case when the diagonal matrix elements do not commute. Can one use a quasi-determinant in this case?

Comment: @kevinkayaks, then it seems that you only need that the quasi-determinant of $M$ is zero, the quasideterminant of $V$ is the sum of the $v_j$ and the quasi-determinant of a product is the product of the quasi-determinants.

Comment: Yes, was looking into this. The problem is that one needs the "inverse" of a matrix element for a quasi-determinant. Given that the matrix elements are differential operators I'm not exactly sure how to handle that